# Error: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: java, android

I'm new and only started learning, so pardon if the error is stupid, I just can't figure out what I did wrong, even after looking at other similar answers. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.android.guessthenumberpuzzle, PID: 2428
                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                      at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:495)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:862)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                      at com.example.android.guessthenumberpuzzle.ListAdapter.getView(ListAdapter.java:27)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2362)
                      at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1326)
                      at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1233)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1117)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:389)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Application terminated.
```

And here are the files:

Game.java

```
package com.example.android.guessthenumberpuzzle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Game extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    }
    ArrayList<List> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void submit(View view) {
        EditText number1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num_1);
        int no1=Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());

        EditText number2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num_2);
        int no2=Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());

        EditText number3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num_3);
        int no3=Integer.parseInt(number3.getText().toString());

        arrayList.add(new List(no1, no2, no3));

        ListAdapter arrayAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, arrayList);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.past_answers);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

activity_game.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkYellow"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/lightPurple"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Make your guess:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="1"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="1"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="submit"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/past_answers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_1_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_2_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_3_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ListView>
```

List.java

```
package com.example.android.guessthenumberpuzzle;

/**
 * Created by Abhijeet on 08-07-2017.
 */

public class List {

    private int mNum1;
    private int mNum2;
    private int mNum3;

    public List(int num1, int num2, int num3){
        mNum1 = num1;
        mNum2 = num2;
        mNum3 = num3;
    }

    public int getNum1(){
        return mNum1;
    }

    public int getNum2(){
        return mNum2;
    }

    public int getNum3(){
        return mNum3;
    }
}
```

ListAdapter.java

```
package com.example.android.guessthenumberpuzzle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List> {

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<List> arrayList) {
        super(context, 0, arrayList);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        List currentItem = getItem(position);

        TextView num1View = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.num_1_view);
        num1View.setText(currentItem.getNum1());

        TextView num2View = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.num_2_view);
        num2View.setText(currentItem.getNum2());

        TextView num3View = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.num_3_view);
        num3View.setText(currentItem.getNum3());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: listItemView = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: Use above line for inflating your view

Comment: @RanjanDas Where? I tried at where I thought it would be, but the context.getSys--- doesn't work, nor does getContext().getSys---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the layout *list_item.xml*.

You cannot add items to a `ListView` like that (it doesn't even make much sense for the `ListView` item to be a `ListView`).

I'm pretty sure you meant something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_1_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_2_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_3_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```